# I can't see the site with curl but the browser sees

Tags: php, curl

The site is viewed with normal browser and postman but I can't view it with php.

when i request with php curl i am faced with challenge.
It works when I send the same header information as postman.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://juegaenlinea.ec',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 100,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'User-Agent: cherry',
    'Host: juegaenlinea.ec'
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what error or information it produce when calling curl, add below code to see:

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo $response;

// also get the error and response code
$errors = curl_error($curl);
$response = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);

var_dump($errors);
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: string(0) "" int(403) .. It's written like that on the screen. 403 error.

Comment: 403 means your server not allow access to internet, curl command is asking to open the browser from the server and get the result, it could be your server not allow accessing internet or website.

Comment: in my normal browser but accessing the site. with the same ip and the same header information. Please try it yourself.

Comment: Yes I try it, there's no issue with website, the issue is with accessing the website from your php server, is this php server running on local or not? do you have access to ssh? You can try to ping from your php server to see do it allow network or not, i have same issue cause the server not allow accessing internet from the server

Comment: postman but he sees the site.. but when the user agent changes, he sees the site. I'm doing the same with php, it doesn't work. An algorithm is used here and I can't find it :( ... pictures here..   [403 image](https://ibb.co/fvhBBKR) --- [200 image](https://ibb.co/wBzHT5m)